# Java: Is it possible to have a generic class that only takes types that can be compared?

Tags: java, generics

I wanted to do something along the lines of:

```
public class MyClass<T implements Comparable> {
    ....
}
```

But I can't, since, apparently, generics only accept restrictions with subclasses, and not interfaces.

It's important that I'm able to compare the types inside the class, so how should I go about doing this? Ideally I'd be able to keep the type safety of Generics and not have to convert the T's to Object as well, or just not write a lot of code overall. In other words, the simplest the better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `implements` is wrong. It only accepts `extends` or `super`. You can use here `extends`:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    // ...
}
```

To learn more about Generics, you may find [this tutorial (PDF)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) useful.

Comment: Java's syntax is a little inconsistent there. If Generics had been part of the original design, there probably would be no `implements` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it is:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    ....
}
```

If you just do `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, then it won't work for subclasses of comparable classes.

Answer (score 1):

Also for interfaces you have to use extends. So in your case it would be:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> {
....
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, you missed a bracket.